# Exception class EIdReadTimeout with message 'Read timed out' [Indy-IdFTP]

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, indy10

I want to download a file from FTP. If the file is small (usually under 1000MB) it works. However, if the file is big I get an EIdReadTimeout. Why? Should I keep the connection alive? From what I know reading data has its own channel so I don't have to keep the connection alive.

What is odd is that the exception appears at the end of the Get (after Get successfully downloads the whole file): FTP.Get(Name, TempGzFile, TRUE, FALSE) !!!!

Documentation:

> TIdFTP.ReadTimeout - Number of milliseconds to wait for an FTP protocol response.
>
> TIdFTP.TransferTimeout - Timeout value for read operations on the data channel for the FTP
> client.

By default ReadTimeout is set to 60sec and TransferTimeout to 10sec.

---

I a using Delphi XE7 (which I guess uses Indy 10). The Passive property for my IdFTP is set to false.

Comment: Remove the timeout, or make it bigger. In any case, downloading a large file or unknown file size shouldn't have a timeout at all, or perhaps should be set to a large time. Imagine someone using a very slow internet connection. Are you using Active or Passive mode? And which version of Indy?

Comment: I'm not sure which timeout without brushing up my FTP knowledge, I abandoned using FTP for being unstable (for program use) and moved on to HTTP a long time ago.  But somewhere you have a timeout. If not, then it must be a problem on the server-side.

Comment: Even if someone could answer without seeing your complete setup, the answer may be substantially different depending on Indy version and FTP mode. You need to include those. But I'm guessing if you don't have a timeout, then the server probably does. Have you tried on different servers?

Comment: Based on your edit, you should look at the `TransferTimeout`. If there is no timeout set there, then you'll need to consult with the Server's vendor. Perhaps there's a bug in Indy 10 and most likely Remy will be here soon to shed some light on that subject :-)

Comment: TransferTimeout is 10 seconds? Have you tried increasing this? That may very well be your issue.

Comment: Apologies I must leave, I have an eye problem and cannot keep staring at my screen :-(

Comment: What file size is the server reporting? Does it differ from the actual size?

Comment: The file is downloaded just right. The size is ok. The content of the downloaded file is not corrupt. It just raises the exception as soon as it finish the download (Get).

Comment: Right, but does that file size match the size reported by Indy?

Comment: You are downloading a 1 GB (1000 Mega Bytes) file in less than 15 minutes, and you consider that a small file!?!  I remember when a 1200 baud modem was the speed king for downloading files.

Comment: Indeed, bear in mind some people out there still use dial-up...

Comment: I remember when I used to use dial-up and could download 3MB in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FTP protocol uses multiple TCP/IP connections - one for the main command/response connection, and separate connections for data transfers.  While a data transfer is in progress, the main command connection sits idle.  Once the transfer is finished, the command connection receives a response.

If you are passing through a router/firewall that is not FTP-aware, the command connection is likely to get killed if it sits idle for too long during a large transfer.  The connection is usually not killed "gracefully", so even the OS does not know the connection is gone.  When `TIdFTP` then tries to read a transfer response that never arrives, it times out.

To account for that, use the `TIdFTP.NATKeepAlive` property to enable TCP/IP level keep-alives on the command connection during transfers.  Set `NATKeepAlive.UseKeepAlive` to True, and set `NATKeepAlive.IdleTimeMS` (the idle timeout before keepalives start sending) and `NATKeepAlive.IntervalMS` (the interval between each keepalive) to suitable values.

Note, however, that `IdleTimeMS` and `IntervalMS` are only implemented for Windows 2000+, Linux, and BSD at this time. Other platforms use defaults provided by the OS (which tend to be very large). If you need to customize the values on those platforms, you can use the `TIdFTP.OnDataChannelCreate` and `TIdFTP.OnDataChannelDestroy` events to call `TIdFTP.Socket.Binding.SetSocketOption()` directly as needed.

Comment: Set them to whatever you want.  They are Indy-level timeouts, not TCP-level timeouts. They are however long you want Indy to wait for individual bytes.  I usually leave them at their defaults, or set them to 10-15+ seconds to account for network lag.

Comment: Look at their product specifications.

Comment: If it does not explicitly state that FTP is supported, then you will likely have to deduce whether it really is or not, or just contact the vendor and ask.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked. Now I only have to fix the Connection closed gracefully error.