# Network problems while using Indy

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy

```
function UploadToFTP(file: string ; PathSrv : string): Boolean;
var 
  server, port, user , password: string;
  SR : TSearchRec;
begin
  Result := True;
  FEventLogger := TEventLogger.Create('Upload FTP');
  if file <> '' then
  begin
    try
            server := FServer;
            port := FPort;
            user := FUserName;
            password:= FPassword;
            FindFirst(file, faArchive, SR);
            try   // try except
                idftp1.Host:= server;
                idftp1.Port := StrToInt(port);
                idftp1.Username:= user;
                idftp1.Password:= password;
                idftp1.Connect();
                idftp1.Put(file,PathSrv+SR.Name);
            except on E: Exception do   begin
                Result:= False;
                FEventLogger.LogMessage('Exception : ' + E.Message , EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE , 0, 2);
                WriteToLog('Exception: '+ file+' error message: '+  E.Message);
             end;
           end;
    finally

    end;
  end;  
end;
```

So I have this function that does an ftp upload to some large files on sometimes slow networks. I've tested it localy and it works ok, but on slow networks i get this eror in 99% of the time.

```
The specified network name is no longer available.
```

This is a very strange behavior, becouse the FTP is located on a server that has no disconnecting issues. I also try to watch, and it start the file upload and it does almost all the upload before throwing this error. So for example if I have a 100MB file it does 99MB of the upload then throws the error.

Any ideas what is causing this error or what can I do?

Also from time to time I have an other error

```
Socket Error # 10054

Connection reset by peer.
```

To mention,i've tried to upload this files using filezilla and it works, so the problem is somewhere in that code, I might miss something.

Comment: Which Delphi do you use or even better which version of Indy do you use? I suspect this might be related to some time-outs, but I guess that should raise a different error.

Comment: Make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy that has the `TIdFTP.NATKeepAlive` property, and enable it during large transfers. That will help with timeout issues due to the command socket being idle too long while a transfer is in progress.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i've added the NATKeepAlive properties to my function. I'll try it later on and see if ther are any improvements, still I don't think that will solve my main error The specified network name is no longer available.  Becouse i can transfer just fine every amount of data, except ( from my guess ) the last set of bytes or something like this.

Comment: @SilverWarior this an aplication build in Delphi 7 but I've compiled it also on XE7. So you can assume it's built in XE7.

Comment: That error message is system error code 64 `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED`. I have never seen that error code reported by WinSock's BSD-based socket API, but I have seen it reported by `WSARecv()` during socket disconnects. It is just the way Microsoft sometimes reports lost connections. The timing of the error happens at the end of the transfer because that is the next time when `TIdFTP` reads from the command socket (to read the server's final response). During the transfer, the command socket is not touched (hence `NATKeepAlive`), so lost connections are not detected until the end of the transfer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau still i get the same error even with the NATKeepAlive option set. I've used this settings. IdFTP1.NATKeepAlive.UseKeepAlive := True;
IdFTP1.NATKeepAlive.IdleTimeMS := 10000;
IdFTP1.NATKeepAlive.IntervalMS := 1000;

Comment: Which OS platform is your app running on? `IdleTimeMS` and `IntervalMS` are currently only implemented on Windows, Linux, and BSD. For other platforms, the OS handles the timeouts. For those, you would have to customize the timeouts manually (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29246519/65863). Did you try using a packet sniffer to make sure the TCP keep-alives are actually being sent during long transfers?

Comment: @RemyLebeau it's Windows, i'm not sure if it's Win x32 or Win x64. But it's windows.

Comment: @CiucaS: as long as it is Win2K or later, it does not matter if it is 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau we found the problem. It was the FTP Server. Thank you for the KeepAlive idea.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Symantec Endpoint Protection or KIS (Kaspersky Internet Security) ? Take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/961293), [here](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f138/solved-the-specified-network-file-name-is-no-longer-available-184430.html) and [here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/specified-network-name-no-longer-available-6).

The "*The specified network name is no longer available.*" is caused by Symantec Endpoint Protection 11.0, Symantec has identified this as a known issue.

Btw, in your code don't forget to call .Disconnect() after you're finished uploading the file.

Comment: I've avoided to use the .Disconnect to see if that was the problem in my code ... you can see that in finally there is no code line ( there is where I put the disconnect). No I've read that, there is no Symantec on the FPT Server nor the client machine.